# How does cell updates get propagated to its corresponding replicas?

Tags: cassandra

Consider a table 'X' with each row consisting of six attributes. Suppose 'X' is already filled with N-rows and the setup contains r-replicas in the cluster. Now if I perform an update to only one column of a row. Then only this column updated will be propagated to its corresponding replicas (along with a key identifier). Is my understanding correct or will the whole row be propagated to its replica nodes?

Thanks,

Chethan

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, only the one new column will be set to replicas.  Cassandra is designed to do writes with no disk seeks, so cannot do reads to propagate writes.  (The exception is for counters and some operations on collections, when reads are made on the coordinator for the update.  But still, the column propagated is only the column being updated.)